# Registration and Webforms

Tags: webforms, users

I'm using Drupal 7 - is there any way to view and output the users who've registered with site in a similar way to how Webforms displays submissions and allows you to download and import into Excel?

I can export the users table from the database as a CSV file but I was hoping to find something that would be integrated into the Drupal admin ui (similar to the way Webforms is).

Thank you for any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two modules that you could use, the ['Database Administration'](http://drupal.org/project/dba) and ['Views Excel Export'](http://drupal.org/project/views_export_xls) These are still in alpha and dev for drupal 7 but might worth a try.